# How to make coloured buttons in bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, navbar

I want to have a big red "Donate" button with white text in the navber, and my solution was `<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Donate Now</a>`. However, the button seems to turn transparent on hover.

I've also tried `<span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>` and `<p class="btn btn-danger">Donate Now</p>`, but the former is too small, while the latter seems strange on hover.

```html
<head>
  <title>
    Test
  </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/static/knowledge/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Donate Now</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

In case my problem cannot be reproduced by the code above, I also created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2dr4w8e/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used a label in your fiddle instead of a button. And you're not supposed to use buttons where a Navigation link belongs, but you're able to bypass this with a simple wrapper.

```
<li>
    <span>
       <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Donate Now</a>
    </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code on your custom style sheet

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: red!important;
    border: 1px solid red!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> try this may be this will help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <p class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Donate Now</p>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```